# Bootstrap4 and Datatables Integration not working

Tags: javascript, datatables, bootstrap-4

I'm attempting to integrate datatables with bootstrap 4 and there are some major conflicts. I am getting the page navigation and the buttons in the style of bootstrap 4 but my table looks like a general HTML table with random bolded borderlines. I believe that my styles are getting overridden somewhere but I can't for the life of me figure out where... 
[image]

imgur link here https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWLvh.jpg

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/autofill/2.2.2/css/autoFill.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.bootstrap4.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.4.1/css/colReorder.bootstrap4.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/css/fixedColumns.bootstrap4.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.3/css/fixedHeader.bootstrap4.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/keytable/2.3.2/css/keyTable.bootstrap4.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/css/responsive.bootstrap4.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.0.2/css/rowGroup.bootstrap4.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.3/css/rowReorder.bootstrap4.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.4/css/scroller.bootstrap4.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.5/css/select.bootstrap4.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.32/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/autofill/2.2.2/js/dataTables.autoFill.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/autofill/2.2.2/js/autoFill.bootstrap4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.bootstrap4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.colVis.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.flash.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/buttons.print.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.4.1/js/dataTables.colReorder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedcolumns/3.2.4/js/dataTables.fixedColumns.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.3/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/keytable/2.3.2/js/dataTables.keyTable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.0.2/js/dataTables.rowGroup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.3/js/dataTables.rowReorder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/scroller/1.4.4/js/dataTables.scroller.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.5/js/dataTables.select.js"></script>
```

I make sure that there is only 1 import of jquery 3.3.1 and 1 import of bootstrap's css and bootstrap.min.js.

EDIT: HTML for the table that I am using.

```
<div id="similar-results" class="tabcontent">
<h3>Similar Documents</h3>
<table border="1" class="dataframe table display" id="example">
```

Comment: Please post your html code of table

Comment: @RohithMurali sorry, i have edited the post and included the html code for the table

Answer (score 1):

From the [Bootstrap documentation on tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/):

> Due to the widespread use of tables across third-party widgets like
>   calendars and date pickers, we’ve designed our tables to be opt-in.

Have you added the `.table` class to your `<table>` element?

Comment: thanks for the reply -- yes I have the table class in my table element. I have updated my post with the html for the table